# Sharing a function between different methods of class

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to declare a function inside class?

If yes, I'm trying to declare **function age()** inside the class, but i think it is not possible on JavaScript or maybe I'm wrong.

I do not want to put it outside the class because the code looks more organized like this. What are the options available?

My code is below.

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    cat() {
        console.log(`Meow! It is cat and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(age('cat'));
    }

    dog() {
        console.log(`Au! It is dog and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(age('dog'));
    }

    function age(animal){
        if(animal=='cat') return 7;
        if(animal=='dog') return 5;
    }

  }
  
  const fluffy = new Animal('Fluffy');
  fluffy.cat();

  const billy = new Animal('billy');
  billy.dog();
```

Comment: Syntactically it’s not possible. It has to be a method if you must put it inside a class. So just declare it outside the class, you can still use it inside class.

Comment: Can you talk more about "why"?  I suspect there's a deeper question underlying this one.

Answer (score 4):

You've already declared functions inside of the class, just do the same for `age`. To access it, you need to use `this.age` since JavaScript doesn't look for class instance variables/functions by default.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  cat() {
    console.log(`Meow! It is cat and his name is ${this.name}`);
    console.log(this.age('cat'));
  }

  dog() {
    console.log(`Au! It is dog and his name is ${this.name}`);
    console.log(this.age('dog'));
  }

  age(animal) {
    if (animal == 'cat') return 7;
    if (animal == 'dog') return 5;
  }

}

const fluffy = new Animal('Fluffy');
fluffy.cat();

const billy = new Animal('billy');
billy.dog();
```

Answer (score 4):

As others already said `cat` and `dog` are already functions of `Animal` (member functions).

If you don't want that the `age` function is a member function (belongs to an instance of `Animal`) you can make it `static`:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    cat() {
        console.log(`Meow! It is cat and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(Animal.age('cat'));
    }

    dog() {
        console.log(`Au! It is dog and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(Animal.age('dog'));
    }

    static age(animal){
        if(animal=='cat') return 7;
        if(animal=='dog') return 5;
    }

  }
  
  const fluffy = new Animal('Fluffy');
  fluffy.cat();

  const billy = new Animal('billy');
  billy.dog();
```

If you don't want to make it accessible outside of `Animal` than make it private:

```js
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    cat() {
        console.log(`Meow! It is cat and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(Animal.#age('cat'));
    }

    dog() {
        console.log(`Au! It is dog and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(Animal.#age('dog'));
    }

    static #age(animal){
        if(animal=='cat') return 7;
        if(animal=='dog') return 5;
    }

  }
  
  const fluffy = new Animal('Fluffy');
  fluffy.cat();

  const billy = new Animal('billy');
  billy.dog();
```

However having a private static function is rarely useful. The intent of a static method is that it logically belongs to the class but performs a task that does not require an instance of that class.

Comment: It might be worth to mention private members if they don't want outside code to access the `age`method.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why it is not necessary to put the word function before the method. this word it not mandatory or maybe is it shorhand? I am not sure why when i declare a function outside the class it is mandatory use the word function

Comment: @JessicaBoaventura `why it is not necessary to put the word function before the method` because that's how it is specified in the specification. For a member function there is no `function` keyword required and allowed, because it is implicitly given by the specification that `foo([...]) {` defines a member function. ` I am not sure why when i declare a function outside the class it is mandatory use the word function` because that's how it is specified  in the specification.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jessica You can put it as a method if you want.

But I think anyway in this case you should have a class for cat and another one for dog.

Or pass in the constructor the age but it will mean that the age will not be related to what is the animal.

Long story short you can decide or to create a class for each or to create a method inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in a class, but the correct syntax requires you to omit the 'function' keyword. Also use this keyword to refer to the current object.

```
class Animal {

    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    cat() {
        console.log(`Meow! It is cat and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(this.age('cat'));
    }

    dog() {
        console.log(`Au! It is dog and his name is ${this.name}`);
        console.log(this.age('dog'));
    }

    age(animal){
        if(animal=='cat') return 7;
        if(animal=='dog') return 5;
    }

  }
  
  const fluffy = new Animal('Fluffy');
  fluffy.cat();

  const billy = new Animal('billy');
  billy.dog();
```

Answer (score 0):

well I can come up with 3 way to define some functionality in a class

number one: method ,it is the common one that you are likely to see in class based codes

```
    class Animal{
                 //rest of  class
                 age(){
                      //your function goes here
                      }
}
```

you can latter access it with an instance of class
`const cat = new Animal() cat.age()` 
number two: static ,it is somewhat different because it belong to class itself

```
    class Animal{
                 //rest of  class
                static age(){
                      //your function goes here
                      }
}
```

in this case you don't need to create an instance of class
`Animal.age()` 
and lastly: treating your function as property it is not different from using method but I would recommend method if you want to use this functionality often there are minor differences in** memory usage**
syntax goes like this

```
    class Animal {
constructor(name) {
  this.age= ()=>{//your function}
 }}
```

use **age** like this

```
 const cat = Animal()
 , {age} = cat
 age()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).